# Need SQL to join three or more tables and display all the rows of all three tables even if they don't match

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need information from three tables.  Each table has a field with a three letter month, four digit year key.  Sorry for the formatting issue.

Table Name:------TBL1--------TBL2---------TBL3

Column Name:--WFMnth------PlanMnth-----PYMnth

Row1--------------Jan 2015

Row2-------------------------------Feb 2015

Row3--------------Mar 2015----Mar 2015-----Mar 2015

Row4--------------------------------------------------Apr 2015

I tried a union and a join but I cannot get four rows of data from the three tables by matching.  TBL1.WFMnth = TBL2.PlanMnth OR TBL3.PYMnth. I’m using Access any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are you currently doing to get the data and what is the result?

Answer (score 0):

What you wasnt is an sql full join. Unfirtunately Access doesnt do those... You are going to have to query for the 3 parts (left outer, right outer, inner) and Union them.

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3516561/Implementing-the-Equivalent-of-a-FULL-OUTER-JOIN-in-Microsoft-Access.htm

This article explains it well.

Comment: Thanks Evans I have been chasing this for days.